# Passing string with apostrophe from PHP into JavaScript function

Tags: php, javascript, escaping

A simple problem that I just can't find the 'right' answer too.

I have a PHP script that reads people's names from a database, and display them in a table. In each row, I have hyperlinked the person's name to a JavaScript function that displays a popup with the person's name as the title - the PHP code and resulting html follows:

```
$name = $results['name'];
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup(this, '\' . $name . '\')">' . $name . '</a>';
```

With html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup(this, 'Steve Smith')">Steve Smith</a>
```

Everything works fine, except when I hit a name that has a hyphen, such as "Bryce D'Arnoud" which results in the apostrophe breaking the html. To get around this issue, I am using the PHP `addslashes()` function, resulting in the following code & html:

```
$name = $results['name'];
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup(this, '\' . addslashes($name) . '\')">' . $name . '</a>';
```

With html:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup(this, 'Bryce D\'Arnoud')">Bryce D'Arnoud</a>
```

Everything functions fine, but for some reason, the JavaScript is not removing the escape character, and in the popup() function, if I alert out name, I see "Bryce D\'Arnoud"

```
function popup(t, name) {
  alert(name);
}
```

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, life would be a lot easier if you didn't mix JavaScript in your markup. Instead, have PHP form semantic markup, and access the data with JavaScript:

```
$name = $results['name'];
echo '<a href="#" class="popup" data-name="' . $name . '">' . $name . '</a>';
```

And then access the value (am using jQuery for this for terseness):

```
$('.popup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert($(this).attr('data-name'));
});
```

And in native JS (I think):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('popup').onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    e.preventDefault();

    alert(this.getAttribute('data-name'));
};
```

Comment: Interesting... but there's no way that code generates valid HTML, is there?

Comment: Sure it does, `data-` attributes are a standard part of HTML5.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping to avoid having to load jQuery to do a simple onclick call, but will keep this solution as my fallback.

Comment: @Paul - You don't need to include jQuery to do this. Assuming you want to keep the inline onclick handler just say `onclick="popup(this)"` and then within your `popup(t)` function get the name with `t.getAttribute('data-name')` (remove the second parameter to `popup()` and set the `data-name` attribute as Eli said).

Comment: My last code snippet doesn't have any jQuery in it at all, and it still doesn't mix markup and JS.

Comment: Thanks Eli, @nnnnnn, hadn't seen this pattern before, works like a charm.

Comment: Quick follow up relating to using this pattern and JSON here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561623/passing-php-generated-json-via-semantic-markup

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't escaping the double quotes work? (not tested)

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"popup(this,'$name')\">$name</a>";
```

**EDIT:** Sorry for missing the point. Using `preg_replace` to replace the single quotes with their HTML entities might do it, though.

```
echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup(this,\'' . preg_replace("/'/",'&#39;',$name) . "')\">$name</a>";
```

**EDIT 2** In fact converting all those in `$name` might be cleaner:

```
$name = preg_replace("/'/", '&#39;', $results['name']);
echo "<a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"popup(this,'$name')\">$name</a>";
```

Comment: It helps me a lot. @inhan

Comment: Thanks for time saving! It helps me.