# Passing PHP-generated JSON via semantic markup

Tags: php, javascript, json

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561040/passing-string-with-apostraphe-from-php-into-javascript-function), it was pointed out that using semantic markup can be a really clean way to pass data to an `onclick` function, along the lines of the code below.

I have a second question relating to passing JSON and having the receiving function recognize it as such. I have a PHP generated JSON value of `[{"authed":"2012-03-04 17:24:24"},{"authed":"2012-03-04 11:44:38"}]` that I need to pass to a function. echoing that straight into the `<a>` tag won't work, so I am using `urlencode()` to get:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-auth="%5B%7B%22authed%22%3A%222012-03-04+17%3A24%3A24%22%7D%2C%7B%22authed%22%3A%222012-03-04+11%3A44%3A38%22%7D%5D" onclick="popup(this)">click</a>
```

Unfortunately, when I alert this out from popup(), I via the following code:

```
function popup(t) {
  var auth = t.getAttribute('data-auth');

  alert(decodeURI(auth));
}
```

I get

```
[{"authed"%3A"2012-03-04+17%3A24%3A24"}%2C{"authed"%3A"2012-03-04+11%3A44%3A38%22"}]
```

which JSON.parse() is unable to handle. Any suggestions on decoding/passing JSON using this pattern?

Comment: `so I am using urlencode() to get:` --- why so? You don't use it in a url

Comment: @zerkms if I don't, all that I get in popup is "[{", everything else is cut off as the first occurrence of a double quote seems to be interpreted as the end of the data-auth attribute.

Comment: You need to use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape for html--like you should be doing for *everything* you echo out in html. Don't use `urlencode()`, which is for encoding parts of a url path or query parameter.

Comment: @FrancisAvila That did it, you've got the anser if you post that below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape for html--like you should be doing for *everything* you echo out in html. (You are doing that right? To prevent generating invalid html?) Don't use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), which is for encoding parts of a url path or query parameter.

```
<?php
$data = array(array('authed'=>'2012-03-04 17:24:24'), array('authed'=>'2012-03-04 11:44:38'));
$jsondata = json_encode($data);
?>
<a data-auth="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($jsondata, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')?>" onclick="popup(this)">click</a>
```